# Facebook startForPostWithGraphPath completionHandler block not called if run from background thread

Tags: objective-c, facebook, objective-c-blocks

I am adding error handling to my code that post a message to Facebook, but am hitting an odd behavior that I am trying to understand.  In my completion handler for FB's startForPostWithGraphPath I check to see if there is an error, if there is then I wait a few seconds before trying to post again.  The issue I am hitting is that when I try to call the method to post this message a second time, I run it on the main thread it works fine.  If I try to run it on the background thread it fails silently.  As in the completion handler is never called the second time.

works

```
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^(void){
                    [MYSocial shareToOpenGraph:poll];
               });
```

Fails

```
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
               ^(void){
                 [MYSocial shareToOpenGraph:poll];
               });
```

I am curious if anyone else has any experience with FB request methods needing to be called on the main thread.  It seems to me that calling retry logic on a background thread is the correct behavior, but obviously is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

i can confirm that the request works on the main thread & fails on the background thread in my application.